# alert message displaying while refresh the browser using pageregisterstartupscript

Tags: message, alert

I am displaying alert message for un authenticated user but if refresh the browser the again alert is displaying.

```
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "alert", "<script language=JavaScript>" + Environment.NewLine + "alert(\"" + msg + "\")" + Environment.NewLine + ";</script>");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If(user.IsAuthenticated)
{
//do something
}
else
{
 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "alert", "<script language=JavaScript>" + Environment.NewLine + "alert(\"" + msg + "\")" + Environment.NewLine + ";</script>");
}
```

depending on what technology you use if you just want to show the message the first time you load the page it works differently, I'm sorry if I'm prejudice if I say that I guess it's a WebForms application but then it should be something like

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "alert", "<script language=JavaScript>" + Environment.NewLine + "alert(\"" + msg + "\")" + Environment.NewLine + ";</script>");
}
```